# attached process error VS C++ .NET

Tags: .net, c++, debugging

When I go to

> Debug -> Start

I  get the error:

> "Unable to attach to machine 'mypc' Do
>   you want to continue anyway? YES/NO

I did not attach a proces and am not sure why it is coming up. (Also, when I hit YES to the error, it does not run.)

How do I remove all attachments on the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a problem with your project configuration settings.

Right click on the project in Solution Explorer and click Properties.  Go to the Debugging Tab.  Make sure that you're debugging on your machine.  In the "Remote Settings" option your connection should be Local.  You also want to make sure the option to "Attach" is set to No.